# Making ngModel recognize changes to a value despite it being the same after pipes

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I have a component containing an input field bound to a number via ng model like so:

```
<input [ngModel]="number | percent:‘1.2’ | wrapPipe" (ngModelChange)="modify($event)"/>
```

Additionally, number is passed in via the @Input tag.

```
@Input() number: number;
```

The percent pipe removes any unnecessary precision such that numbers like 1.44444 will become 1.44 and adds a % sign.
The wrap pipe simply calls WrappedValue.wrap on the formatted number like so:

```
transform(value: any, …args: any[]): any {
  return WrappedValue.wrap(value);
}
```

The point of this pipe is to make sure that the ng change is triggered even when the formatted number does not change. So for example, if number's value changed from 1.444 to 1.4444, I still want it to convert it to 1.44 and add % via the percent pipe. This works for the most part, except I get the following error:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'model: [object Object]'.
>   Current value: 'model: null'.

model's current value is either null if nothing is in the field or the formatted number. So my question is: Where should I unwrap the value so that it still triggers change detection and formats the number, but does not throw the error.

Comment: This might help https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4